# Google OAuth2 cannot get profile info

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, openid

I'm using the `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?` endpoint to obtain the `id_token`.

The scopes are `openid profile email`.

The problem is that when I try to verify that `id_token` I get `iss, azp, aud, sub, email, email_verified, iat, exp, jti`. And as you can see there is no any profile info like `given_name, family_name, picture`.

The [official doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) says that it should contain profile info:

```
// These seven fields are only included when the user has granted the "profile" and
 // "email" OAuth scopes to the application.
 "email": "testuser@gmail.com",
 "email_verified": "true",
 "name" : "Test User",
 "picture": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-kYgzyAWpZzJ/ABCDEFGHI/AAAJKLMNOP/tIXL9Ir44LE/s99-c/photo.jpg",
 "given_name": "Test",
 "family_name": "User",
 "locale": "en"
```

All permissions are granted.

**UPDATE**

So in case anyone ever needs it.

As **[Vladimir Serykh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3503521/vladimir-serykh)** mentioned, to get profile info we need to hit the `/userinfo` endpoint. But this endpoint takes `access_token` as a Bearer token in a `Authorization` header, so you need obtain that too.

So basically we need to call the OAuth2 with the `response_type='id_token token'` query parameter. After that the responseUrl will contain `access_token` too.

Next you just need to call the `https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo` endpoint with a Authorization header set to `Bearer your_access_token`. You will get a response wiht the profile info:

```
"sub": "user_id",
"name": "Name Lastname",
"given_name": "Name",
"family_name": "Lastname",
"picture": "pic_url",
"email": "example@gmail.com",
"email_verified": true,
"locale": "en"
```

Thank you again, **[Vladimir Serykh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3503521/vladimir-serykh)**

Comment: `// These seven fields are only included when the user has granted the "profile" and "email" OAuth scopes to the application.`. When you request `profile` and `email` scopes, it doesn't necessarily means the they will be granted. I suggest you to look into that.

Comment: BTW, are you sure that you're checking `id_token` not `access_token`?

Comment: It's `id_token` because the request url that I hit contains `response_type: 'id_token'`.
About the permissions. The security tab of logged in apps says `Basic account info: -See your personal info, including any personal info you've made publicly available; -View your email address`

Comment: How do you know that there is no expected claims in the token? `The problem is that when I try to verify that id_token`. What do you do exactly? Try to decode original token string on http://jwt.io

Comment: Tried the jwt.io, payload is still the same. I'm using 'google-auth-library' to verify the `id_token`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear how old the documentation is (by the [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) you provided) and is it relevant to your case.

I know that different Identity Providers can work slightly different. And I know cases when you should make a separate call with obtained ID token to `/userinfo` endpoint to get user info.

---

There is some different Google documentation for **Google Identity Platform**.

1. It has description of **ID tokens**.

   https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtainuserinfo

   > Google ID Tokens may contain the following fields (known as claims):
   >
   > [image: ID Token]

   Notice that it doesn't have `always` in **Provided** column. I think that it could be different for different APIs.
2. The same docs have section "**Obtaining user profile information**"

   It explains where to get the `/userinfo` endpoint URL and how to call it. In the response you should receive the info you need.

---

My guess why it's not working in your case is that you are using `/tokeninfo` endpoint. It's not a part of OpenID Connect standard. It just validates the token and parses it (does the same job as https://jwt.io). And the original ID token doesn't contain that claims for some reason. Therefore `/tokeninfo` endpoint doesn't return them to you.

But according to Google's documentation and you should use `/userinfo` endpoint to obtain user info claims.

You can find description of this endpoint in OpenID Connect specification:
https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo

> 5.3 UserInfo endpoint
>
> The UserInfo Endpoint is an OAuth 2.0 Protected Resource that returns Claims about the authenticated End-User. To obtain the requested Claims about the End-User, the Client makes a request to the UserInfo Endpoint using an Access Token obtained through OpenID Connect Authentication.

Comment: Thanks, you are a lifesaver, it works now! I'll update my question for others.